# Can't seem to dump a data packet into a file

Tags: php, server

Alright, so for this project the language I'm using is PhP.

I'm creating a advance cache system to save CPU cycles in my program. By encoding a chunk once, many CPU cycles can get saved and the results would be a faster server.

```
if(!isset($this->chunkCache[$index])){
        $pk = new BatchPacket();
        $pk->payload = $payload;
        $pk->encode();
        $pk->isEncoded = true;
        $this->chunkCache[$index] = $pk;
        file_put_contents("cache/" . $this->getName() . "/" . $x . "_" . $z . ".dat", $pk);
    }
```

So the goal here is to encode a chunk, save it into RAM (So it can be used by other players) then create a .dat file that saves the packet so in the future I can skip the encoding part.

Now my problem is that the files that get generated are empty. I don't know why. What I need is the file to contain the $pk packet. Something that should look like this:

```
["isEncoded"]=>
bool(true)
["channel"]=>
int(0)
["offset"]=>
int(0)
["buffer"]=>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you also get an error in the php error log? I would expect there to be one

Comment: No errors. Just empty files generate.

Comment: Nothing like `Catchable fatal error: Object of class BatchPacket could not be converted to string in .....`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was just about to suggest that. from what i can see `$pk` is an object and `file_put_contents` only accepts either a string, array or stream resource as it's second argument. you might need to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the object to a string first then [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when you import the file back into php

Comment: No errors while running this code, but I did get an error like that when I tried to execute some code that used this file. I believe this is the problem however. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Add these 3 lines directly after `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Just in case you are developing on a LIVE server and error reporting is turned off

Comment: @Memor-X Good idea. I will try that.

Comment: Maybe you should use something like MemcacheD instead of trying to implement this yourself.

Comment: @Memor-X It worked! However, is the function to time consuming? I may need to run this on a different thread.